# Class EmailAddressCriteria not found (SimpleJavaMail)

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

I try to use the `SimpleJavaMail` library, but I think I missed something when importing the JAR of the API and it's dependencies. I use Java 8 (openjdk), and here is a list of the external JARs I added in my Eclipse Oxygen project configuration :

- `slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar` (the 1.7.13 version seems to be the version of `SLF4J` used in `SimpleJavaMAil` since version 2.5.1 according to [its GitHub](https://github.com/bbottema/simple-java-mail))
- `slf4j-simple-1.7.13.jar`
- `javax.mail.jar` version 1.6.1
- `simple-java-mail-5.0.3.jar`

Here is a code sample:

```
import org.simplejavamail.email.Email;
import org.simplejavamail.email.EmailBuilder;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.Mailer;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.MailerBuilder;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.config.TransportStrategy;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Email notif = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
                .to("someone@somewhere.fr")
                .withSubject("Bla")
                .withPlainText("Lorem ipsum\nLorem ipsum")
                .buildEmail();

        Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder
                .withSMTPServer("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "foo@gmail.com", "bar")
                .withTransportStrategy(TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS)
                .withSessionTimeout(10 * 1000)
                .clearEmailAddressCriteria() // turns off email validation
                .withDebugLogging(true)
                .buildMailer();

        mailer.sendMail(notif);
    }
}
```

The exception I have running that code trought Eclipse on my Linux is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hazlewood/connor/bottema/emailaddress/EmailAddressCriteria
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.MailerGenericBuilder.<init>(MailerGenericBuilder.java:152)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.MailerBuilder$MailerRegularBuilder.<init>(MailerBuilder.java:136)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.MailerBuilder.withSMTPServer(MailerBuilder.java:49)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hazlewood.connor.bottema.emailaddress.EmailAddressCriteria
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Maven Central's [`pom.xml` for simple-java-mail-5.0.3](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.simplejavamail%7Csimple-java-mail%7C5.0.3%7Cjar) you are missing the following dependency

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.bbottema</groupId>
  <artifactId>emailaddress-rfc2822</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I think you should use a build tool like Maven or Gradle to set up your project instead of adding the JAR files manually to avoid problems with missing dependencies.